# Rails Engines not autoloading models with namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

I have an Rails app which uses an Engine called: `Competitions`. When I start the Rails server and I load the page for the first time, it says:
`LoadError: Unable to autoload constant Tournament, expected /home/stein/RubyProjects/my_app/engines/competitions/app/models/competitions/tournament.rb to define it`

Rails doesn't seem to know that there is a `Competitions::Tournament` class in the file, it only looks for `Tournament`. How can I make it that Rails searches for `Competitions::Tournament` instead of `Tournament`?

Ruby version: 2.1.1
Rails version: 4.1.0
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Answer (score 2):

I'm on the same versions of Ruby/Rails and I also have an Engine with models that autoload. Did your define you models within the Module that defines your Engine Gem? i.e:

Assuming your engine is called Competitions:

```
module Competitions
  class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

You can also place the Module inline:

```
class Competitions::Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

This is because Rails looks for modules/class within the hierarchy of your file system so if you have a class within `app/models/competitions/another_namespace/tournament.rb` Then you'd have to wrap your model in the modules named by the directories `competitions` and `another_namespace` as `Competitions::AnotherNamespace::Tournament`.

Try that and reboot your dummy or host app.